# Angular 6 nested route params

Tags: angular, routes, nested

I am having a route for `Level:/id` in my routing component. I want to access the Difficulty id. How can I use router params in this case? Since it is dependent on first getting the Level id then moving one step down to the Settings property, and finally to the Difficulty id?

So the structure looks something like this:

```
Level = {
  id: "some_id",
  name: "some_name",
  Settings: [
    Type: "sometype",
    Difficulty: {
      id: "difficulty_id"
    }
  ]
}
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Inside the component that gets loaded on `Level:/id`, you can inject the `ActivatedRoute` as a dependency. You can then `subscribe` to the `params` property on it to get the current params.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...
id;
constructor(..., private route: ActivatedRoute, ...) {}
...

this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.id = params['id'];

  // OR if the id is of type number
  // this.id = +params['id'];
});
```